# Fragment lose data from ViewModel after recreating view

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-livedata

Imagine that you have 2 fragments connected to one (or more) viewModel(s) and inside of activity you'll switch between them. Once you open fragment, viewModel works as expected, so I start listening for changes from onCreate method, code example:

```
 viewModel =  new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), new InventoryTasksFactory()).get(InventoryTasksViewModel.class);
    viewModel.inventoryTasksResponse().observe(this, new Observer<Response<List<InventoryTask>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Response<List<InventoryTask>> listResponse) {
            handleResponse(listResponse);
        }
    });
```

But when you switching to another fragment and going back, fragment becomes blank. I understand that fragment listening changes inside of viewModel, and you should manually getting value from viewModel and I get value from viewModel inside of onCreateView method, code example:

```
 Response<List<InventoryTask>> inventory = viewModel.inventoryTasksResponse().getValue();
    if (inventory!=null){
        handleResponse(inventory);
    }
```

Problem is that Response has 3 states: Running, Success, Error, and depends on those states view is updating. So, in first fragment opening, view updating twice and it leads to skipping frames and display blinking.

I was thinking about keeping data inside of fragment, but I want to avoid data duplicating. Besides of that, in case of sharedViewModel, you'll get issues about updating data inside of fragment!

Please, help me!

Comment: "view updating twice" can you explain it? and you use fragment transaction right?

Comment: Thanks for that question! Yes, transactions with animation. What I've got now is that Response.Running and  Response.Success becomes to a stack of Responses and when view is creating, view make updating as Running and then updating as Success and that leads to skipping frames. So, only what could I do is to delay process of getting data from repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observing your data from `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)` might work out.

Comment: Good luck :D
I had an equal issue a bit ago and if my brain didn't mess that one up, this was what helped it.

Comment: Thanks for help)) Test was successfull and code became much cleaner, no need in checking for nullability of value from livedata))

Comment: Glad I could help @JohnyDeph :)